# Vishnu Prayer while invocation of other Deities

Tags: vishnu, puja, navagraha, sadhana, upasana

Is there any way I can invoke and praise (Budh, Brihaspati, Mangala) and various other devatas and rishis before I start my prayer solely dedicated to the lotus feet of Vishnu?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can certainly invoke and praise other devatas (gods) and rishis (sages) before beginning your prayer dedicated to Vishnu. In Hindu tradition, it's common to offer respect and homage to various deities and spiritual figures before focusing on a specific deity or aspect of the divine. This practice is known as "upasana" or "puja" and is a way of acknowledging the interconnectedness of different aspects of the divine.

You can begin by reciting mantras or prayers dedicated to Budh (Mercury), Brihaspati (Jupiter), Mangala (Mars), and other devatas and rishis you wish to invoke. You can offer praise, gratitude, and seek blessings from them for guidance and support on your spiritual journey. Afterward, you can transition into your prayer dedicated to the lotus feet of Vishnu, focusing your devotion and offering your prayers to Him. This sequential approach allows you to pay homage to various aspects of the divine before centering your worship on Vishnu.

Comment: I an going to upvote this answer, but I want a more direct way of doing it.

Comment: Use verses from Navagraha strotam .

Comment: In what scripture?